# Log4j Log to STDOUT then format to JSON layout for Logstash

Tags: spring, log4j, fluentd

I have a Spring Boot application running in a Kubernetes cluster and a **EFK** stack (like **ELK**, but with instead of Logstash, Fluentd is used as a lightweight alternative to collect logs from all kubernetes pods and sends them to elasticsearch).

In order to adapt the logs to a JSON output, I have used a [logstash-logback-encoder](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder) library:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

And out of the box I had my logs converted to JSON (which is great).

I log to STDOUT, everything gets picked up and sent to Elasticsearch.
No special configuration for logging is needed inside the Spring Boot application.

**But the problem** I have right now is that while reading my logs in realtime from the STDOUT of the Kubernetes pod, they are very hard to read with all the JSON formatting.

Example:

```
{"@timestamp":"2018-02-08T12:49:06.080+01:00","@version":1,"message":"Mapped \"{[/error],produces=[text/html]}\" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)","logger_name":"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2018-02-08T12:49:06.080+01:00","@version":1,"message":"Mapped \"{[/error]}\" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)","logger_name":"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2018-02-08T12:49:06.098+01:00","@version":1,"message":"Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]","logger_name":"org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2018-02-08T12:49:06.098+01:00","@version":1,"message":"Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]","logger_name":"org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2018-02-08T12:49:06.137+01:00","@version":1,"message":"Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]","logger_name":"org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2018-02-08T12:49:06.268+01:00","@version":1,"message":"Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup","logger_name":"org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2018-02-08T12:49:06.333+01:00","@version":1,"message":"Initializing ProtocolHandler [\"http-nio-8080\"]","logger_name":"org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2018-02-08T12:49:06.355+01:00","@version":1,"message":"Starting ProtocolHandler [\"http-nio-8080\"]","logger_name":"org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
```

**What I want to do is** Log to STDOUT in 'normal non-JSON' format then send logs to Fluentd in JSON format.

I am trying to configure two log appenders (one to STDOUT and another in JSON format for Fluentd) but I am pretty sure that this will duplicate the data (Fluentd will get the JSON format AND the STDOUT).

My plan B is to build one image for deployment (without the JSON format) and another for production but this is more like plan Z, tbh because I want to monitor those pods in production as well.

**My question is** How can I do this with possibly one log appender OR without duplicating the data in Fluentd. Is there maybe a different approach that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I was tempted for a solution that was proposed, at the end I just used `jq`, a [json parser](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to view my logs on the cli. I did so in order to avoid duplicating log data and not having to create files nor having to specially configure fluentd for reading logs from files.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using Logback and not Log4j that you have tagged since the logstash library you linked to seems to be written for Logback.

The easiest solution would probably be to configure fluentd to read logs from a file and redirect the JSON appender to that file.

There's an [article](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/in_tail) about the tail input plugin, but essentially you configure it like this:

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!-- JSON appender for log collection -->
  <appender name="json" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/some/path/to/your/file.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>/some/path/to/your/file.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" />
  </appender>

  <!-- Console appender for humans -->
  <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- Set threshold for the console log here if you want the
      log collection to get all log messages regardless of level -->
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
      ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <!-- Tie it all together -->
  <root level="all">
    <appender-ref ref="json" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

**fluentd**

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /some/path/to/your/file.log
  pos_file /some/path/to/your/file.log
  format json
</source>
```

Accourding to the documenation, fluentd will follow rollovers and start from the beginning of the new file after finishing the old file.

If you want the console output to be the same as a regular Spring Boot application you can copy the pattern from [their configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/e92e56dda5d4ed35479b0797bbdd486551665663/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml)